# JSF Primefaces: How to use ternary operator for items inside a <f:selectItems> rendered HTML dropdown list?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl, lombok

Am using JSF Primefaces 7.0 to render an XHTML file to display a list of users (along with their e-mail addresses) inside a single HTML dropdown list.

---

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

User class:

```
package com.myapp.model;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName; 

    // this is their e-mail address
    private String username; 

    public String getName() {

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     
        if (!isBlank(getFirstName())) {
            sb.append(getFirstName()).append(' ');
        }
     
        if (!isBlank(getLastName())) {
            sb.append(getLastName());
        }
     
        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

---

Inside users.xhtml:

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
>
    <f:selectItems
       value="#{userReport.users}"
       var="user"
       itemLabel="#{user.name} (#{user.username})"
       itemValue="#{user}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</html>
```

---

This renders correctly for an individual item if the (`user.name` is not null) inside an HTML dropdown list:

`John Doe (jdoe@email.com)`

---

How can I use a conditional (`<c:if>` with `<c:else>` or even the `? :` ternary operator) to set the `itemLabel` attribute to render just the `user.username` without parenthesis if the `user.name` is empty string or null?

So, it should set to this (the e-mail address) if `user.name` is null or an empty string:

`itemLabel="#{user.username}"`

To make display (if `user.name` is null or empty string):

`jdoe@email.com`

---

Tried doing this:

```
itemLabel="#{not empty user.name ? user.name (user.username) : user.username}"
```

---

Which gives me the following stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Method not found: class com.myapp.model.User.name(java.lang.String)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:749)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class com.myapp.model.User.name(java.lang.String)
    at javax.el.Util.findWrapper(Util.java:373)
    at javax.el.Util.findMethod(Util.java:219)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:149)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:79)
    ... 35 more
```

---

Don't understand why this is the case because the original attribute did find the `User.getName()` method:

```
itemLabel="#{user.name} (#{user.username})"
```

---

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `itemLabel="#{user.name} #{not empty user.username ? '(' + user.username + ')' : ''}"`?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by using the `+=` concatenation operator:

```
itemLabel="#{!empty user.name ? user.name += ' (' += user.username += ')' : user.username}"
```